# Application with multiple Endpoints - Routing [ui5 + node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sapui5

I do have an application with multiple endpoints, the issue is, this new endpoints aren't recognized via an url.

**For example:**

Within `server.js` there is the `GET`-function:

```
app.get('/TwoWonders', function (req, res) {
    var items = [
        {name: 'Example1', location: 'Rome'},
        {name: 'Example2', location: 'Greece'}
    ]
    res.send(items);
});
```

Via the port set in the file, i.e. `localhost:3000/TwoWonders` i could access the contents of `TwoWonders`.

**Issue**
When puting `TwoWonders` to a separate file, `wonders.js`, the `url` appropriate to it would be `localhost:3000/wonders/TwoWonders`, however it doesn't work/isn't recognized. How do i make it work ?

Update: couldnt find the soultion to this issue

Comment: hello, can you clarify what "aren't recognized" means? Not being able to call the URL(HTTP 404) or the ajax function aren't parsing the incoming data?

Comment: @FelixFong, by not being recognized i mean, if you were to type in the url `localhost:3000/wonders/TwoWonders` you would ge the message: `Cannot GET wonders/TwoWonders` instead of being able to see the contents of the `TwoWonders`